# How to translate PHP SoapClient request example to RoR?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, http, soap-client

I'd like to use some web service via its API. In documentation I found an example request written with PHP SoapClient. But I am using RoR and I have no PHP experience. Could someone tell me how should I write the same in RoR, or at least translate it to plain HTTP terminology?

```
<?php
  $soap = new SoapClient(“https://secure.przelewy24.pl/external/wsdl/service.php?wsdl”);
  $test = $soap->TestAccess(“9999”, “anuniquekeyretrievedfromprzelewy24”);
  if ($test)
    echo ‘Access granted’;
  else
    echo ‘Access denied’;
?>
```

Edit: particularly I'd like to know what should I do with `TestAccess` method, because there's no methods in plain HTTP. Should I join this name with URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make your life easier, check out a gem that allows you to simplify SOAP access, like [savon](https://github.com/savonrb/savon).

Then the code could be translated as

```
# create a client for the service
client = Savon.client(wsdl: 'https://secure.przelewy24.pl/external/wsdl/service.php?wsdl')
```

This will automatically parse the possible methods to `client` that are offered in the SOAP API (defined in the WSDL). To list the possible operations, type

```
client.operations
```

In your case this will list

```
[:test_access, :trn_refund, :trn_by_session_id, :trn_full_by_session_id, :trn_list_by_date, :trn_list_by_batch, :trn_full_by_batch, :payment_methods, :currency_exchange, :refund_by_id, :trn_register, :trn_internal_register, :check_nip, :company_register, :company_update, :batch_list, :trn_dispatch, :charge_back, :trn_check_funds, :check_merchant_funds, :transfer_merchant_funds, :verify_transaction, :register_transaction, :deny_transaction, :batch_details]
```

Then to call the method, do the following

```
response = client.call(:test_access, message: { test_access_in: 9999 })
response = client.call(:test_access, message: { 
   test_access_in: 9999 }
   test_access_out: "anuniquekeyretrievedfromprzelewy24" 
)
response.body
 => {:test_access_response=>{:return=>false}}
```

this gets a result, but I have no idea what it means.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work: NoMethodError:
       undefined method `testAccess' for #<Savon::Client:0x0056287feb0890>

Comment: Ok, i did some more digging, and updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I've included an entire controller method that we use in production as an example but essentially you want to pass in your xml/wsdl request as the body of the HTTP request and then parse the response as xml, or what we used below which is [rexml](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/rexml/rdoc/REXML/Document.html) for easier traversing of the returned doc.

```
def get_chrome_styles
  require 'net/http'
  require 'net/https'
  require 'rexml/document'
  require 'rexml/formatters/pretty'

  xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:description7b.services.chrome.com">
        <soapenv:Header/>
        <soapenv:Body>
           <urn:StylesRequest modelId="' + params[:model_id] + '">
              <urn:accountInfo number="[redacted]" secret="[redacted]" country="US" language="en" behalfOf="trace"/>
              <!--Optional:-->
           </urn:StylesRequest>
        </soapenv:Body>
      </soapenv:Envelope>'


  base_url = 'http://services.chromedata.com/Description/7b?wsdl'
  uri = URI.parse( base_url )
  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

  request = Net::HTTP::Post.new("/Description/7b?wsdl")
  request.add_field('Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=utf-8')
  request.body = xml
  response = http.request( request )

  doc  = REXML::Document.new(response.body)

  options = []
  doc.get_elements('//style').each do |division|
    puts division
    options << { :id => division.attributes['id'], :val => division.text }
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json => options.to_json }
  end
end
```

Comment: It doesn't solve my problem, I edited my question to highlight what is the main obstacle for me.